# Circuit editor functionality - current scope

Tags: feature-request

In the circuit editor when you do a time domain simulation you can only look at voltage. In traditional spice packages, its common to be able look at currents also. Usually this is done by highlighting a the port of a part (not the wire connecting two parts, thats a voltage). It would be nice to be able see the current. It would also be nice to type in simple equations to do power analysis. For Example: V(Node1)*V(Node2) or V(Node1)+V(Node2) or V(Node1)*I(Node2). Is this functionality that is desired by the community and could be implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We couldn't make that change if we wanted to. The schematic editor and simulator is Circuit Lab's, and it's behind a paywall now. We're lucky they let us continue to use their software for free.